# Simple While loop database search table

Tags: loops, if-statement, random, while-loop

first of all: Thanks for all the great help I already received through finding answers to questions others posted.

I have a small and easy question for you:

I'm trying to randomly generate a number, but if it exists in the database table, it should keep generating a new numbers until it finds a unique number.

Help would be much appreciated!

```
    $klantnr = rand(1,9);

    $kn = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('select username from users where id="'.$klantnr.'"'));

    while($kn!=0){
       $klantnr = rand(1,9);
      }                                   
echo $klantnr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table with:

```
id integer primary key auto_increment
insert into users (id, username) values (NULL, 'name')
insert into users (username) values ('name')
```

MySQL will generate unique id for you

=== update

```
create table random_id (
    id integer,
    used tinyint,
    primary key(id),
    key idx_used(used)
);

for (0..9999) {
    rand_id = get_random_id();
    insert into random_id (id, used) values (rand_id, 0);
}
```

When need a random id, just fetch one from random_id table:

```
rand_id = select id from random_id where used = 0;
update random_id set used = 1 where id = :rand_id

use rand_id
```

Really it's pre generated random id, if you guarantee the users table's id only from random table, you doesn't need dealing with conflict ids :)

Comment: But this will auto_increment, right? I want it to have a a random number between 1000 and 9999 (i will change the rand(1,9) later.

Comment: Yes, it will auto_increment. If you only use the random number at insert time, you can `while (try insert with random id) { if (mysql says key duplicate) { get a new id } else { break; } }`

Comment: I don't want to insert the value, but to store it in a variable.

Comment: For me, I will create a table to store random generated id, then assign the id as variable. If each time generate id by random and select loop, in the worse conditions may select too many times..